# What is .' appended to end of list for use in bsxfun do?

Tags: matlab

From the Matlab docs for bsxfun an example is given:

```
fun = @(A,B) A.*sin(B);
A = 1:7;
B = pi*[0 1/4 1/3 1/2 2/3 3/4 1].'; % what is the .' at the end?
C = bsxfun(fun,A,B)
```

I understand how to use bsxfun, but I don't understand what .' does? I understand ' to be transpose, but what is .'?

Comment: It's just a normal transpose (i.e. simply swaps the rows with the columns. The `'` operator is actually the complex conjugate transpose. If you have no complex numbers then the two will be the same.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had failed to find documentation on .' directly using doc, hence my confusion. Appreciate your point about it's behavior in the absence of complex numbers. Helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you know you can type things like `help /` or `help .`? You'll get the help for all MATLAB operators and special characters.

In order to get the help on `transpose` like that, you first have to know a bit about MATLAB syntax. It is a bit odd in that the apostrophe serves a triple role:

- to denote strings (quote)
- to escape itself
- for transposing vectors/matrices

The second one allows you to write an literal apostrophe inside a string:

```
>> a = 'This is how it''s done!';
```

This triple role is due to historic reasons, and in my opinion rather unfortunate. Because, if you try

```
>> help .'
```

MATLAB syntax rules dictate that this will be interpreted as

```
>> help('.'')
```

which is an *unterminated string*. Therefore, to get the help on the transposes, you'll have to "escape" the apostrophe:

```
>> help .''
```

Which gives you the answer:

```
...
transpose  - Transpose                         .'
ctranspose - Complex conjugate transpose        ' 
...
```

so the difference is this:

```
>> A = [1+1i  2+2i
        3+3i  4+4i];
>> A'
ans =
   1.0000 - 1.0000i   3.0000 - 3.0000i
   2.0000 - 2.0000i   4.0000 - 4.0000i

>> A.'
ans =
   1.0000 + 1.0000i   3.0000 + 3.0000i
   2.0000 + 2.0000i   4.0000 + 4.0000i
```

Here's some fun you can have with that:

```
>> A' * A.'

ans =
    14    30
    20    44
```

Of course, you could have also gotten the help with `help transpose` or `help ctranspose`, because the apostrophe-notations are just aliases for those longer function names. Those long function names are also the ones to use when you are going into OOP and operator overloading:

```
classdef MyAwesomeClass

    methods

        %// this is how you'd overload the transpose operator for your class:
        function obj = transpose(obj)
            %// implement transpose here
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderfully comprehensive answer Rody. Appreciate it. I did not know about help / or help . to show all operators, very useful. I had done 'doc .'' which doesn't yield help. My bad. I won't comment on the rest of your answer other than to say it is all very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

From [***here***](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)

> **`b = a.'`** computes the *non-conjugate transpose* of matrix `a` and returns
>   the result in `b`.

See difference with following example :

```
>> [1+6i 7-3i 5]'

ans =

   1.0000 - 6.0000i
   7.0000 + 3.0000i
   5.0000          

>> [1+6i 7-3i 5].'

ans =

   1.0000 + 6.0000i
   7.0000 - 3.0000i
   5.0000
```

In your case you've no complex numbers, so the result of two (with or without dot `.`) will be the same

Comment: P0W, if I could give two answer awards I would. Thank you.